# Generating an Equation for Quadratic Bezier Curve

Tags: analytic-geometry

So I know that a standard equation for a quadratic Bezier Curve is:
$C(t)=(1-t)^2P_0+2t(1-t)P_1+t^2P_2$

I have been asked to generate an equation to model my quadratic bezier curve. 
I known that my $t=0.5$ and my control points are: $P_0=(0,1),P_1=(2.74,0.94), P_2=(1.76,5.9)$

Here's an image of my curve if it is helpful:
[Quadratic Bezier Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnNDc.png)

I feel like this should be simple and I'm missing something easy. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Well you just have to plug the values of $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$ into the standard equation that you gave.

I can't really imagine what's causing you difficulty.

Maybe it's confusing that the standard equation is written in "vector" form, with the $x$ and $y$ components/coordinates bundled together. If so, just write the $x$ and $y$ components separately:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= (1-t)^2x_0+2t(1-t)x_1+t^2x_2  \\
y(t) &= (1-t)^2y_0+2t(1-t)y_1+t^2y_2
\end{align}
Now plug in $x_0 = 0$, $y_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 2.74$, $y_1 = 0.94$, $x_2 = 1.76$, $y_2 = 5.9$.